# add to basket with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopping-cart

i'm using this jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#basketItemsWrap li:first").hide();

$(".productPriceWrapRight a img").click(function() {
    var productIDValSplitter    = (this.id).split("_");
    var productIDVal            = productIDValSplitter[1];

    var productX        = $("#productImageWrapID_" + productIDVal).offset().left;
    var productY        = $("#productImageWrapID_" + productIDVal).offset().top;

    if( $("#productID_" + productIDVal).length > 0){
        var basketX         = $("#productID_" + productIDVal).offset().left;
        var basketY         = $("#productID_" + productIDVal).offset().top;         
    } else {
        var basketX         = $("#basketTitleWrap").offset().left;
        var basketY         = $("#basketTitleWrap").offset().top;
    }

    var gotoX           = basketX - productX;
    var gotoY           = basketY - productY;

    var newImageWidth   = $("#productImageWrapID_" + productIDVal).width() / 3;
    var newImageHeight  = $("#productImageWrapID_" + productIDVal).height() / 3;

    $("#productImageWrapID_" + productIDVal + " img")
    .clone()
    .prependTo("#productImageWrapID_" + productIDVal)
    .css({'position' : 'absolute'})
    .animate({opacity: 0.4}, 100 )
    .animate({opacity: 0.1, marginLeft: gotoX, marginTop: gotoY, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHeight}, 1200, function() {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                $(this).remove();

        $("#notificationsLoader").html('<img src="images/loader.gif">');

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "funzioni-carrello.asp",  
            data: { productID: productIDVal, action: "addToBasket"},  
            success: function(theResponse) {

                if( $("#productID_" + productIDVal).length > 0){
                    $("#productID_" + productIDVal).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500);
                    $("#productID_" + productIDVal).before(theResponse).remove();
                    $("#productID_" + productIDVal).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500);
                    $("#productID_" + productIDVal).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
                    $("#notificationsLoader").empty();

                } else {
                    $("#basketItemsWrap li:first").before(theResponse);
                    $("#basketItemsWrap li:first").hide();
                    $("#basketItemsWrap li:first").show("slow");  
                    $("#notificationsLoader").empty();          
                }

            }  
        });  

    });

});



$("#basketItemsWrap li img").live("click", function(event) { 
    var productIDValSplitter    = (this.id).split("_");
    var productIDVal            = productIDValSplitter[1];  

    $("#notificationsLoader").html('<img src="images/loader.gif">');

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "funzioni-carrello.asp",  
        data: { productID: productIDVal, action: "deleteFromBasket"},  
        success: function(theResponse) {

            $("#productID_" + productIDVal).hide("slow",  function() {$(this).remove();});
            $("#notificationsLoader").empty();

        }  
    });  

});
```

});

Then i've the function call like this:

```
<div id="basketWrap">
  <div id="basketTitleWrap">
    <h2>Carrello </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="basketItemsWrap">
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <% 
        'dim getBasket
        getBasket() %>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i modify this so that if the basket is empty it displays a message saying “your basket is empty.” This disappears when you add the first product, and would reappear if you removed all products from your basket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start out with you empty basket, something like this:

```
<div id="basketWrap">
 <div id="empty">Your basket is empty!</div>
 <ul id="itemlist">
  ...
```

when your itemlist is empty, you apply `display:none;` to the `#itemlist`, if its filled `display:none;` to the `#empty` div and `display:block;` for the `#itemlist`.

When you use something like `class="hidden"` you simply could toggle the classes.

ALtnernatively, you could manipulate the innerhtml of your basket via `.html()`.

EDIT:

with the markup given above, add to your function:

```
$("#basketItemsWrap li img").live("click", function(event) {
```

the following code:

```
   if ($("#basketItemsWrap li").length == 1){
       $("#empty").show();
   }
```

(you could use some transition, too.)

And to the success-part of you ajax call in the add-product function you add:

```
   $("#empty").hide();
```

Comment: Your question leads me to the assumption, you just copied the code;)? Could you provide a live-example of that code? Or at least a html-codesnippet with filled basket?

Comment: The original script is that example
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/creating-a-slick-ajaxed-add-to-basket-with-jquery-and-php/

but i'm converted to ASP Classic and i've to implemented it with above question :)

Comment: added sample code, how it should be working. Plz don't be mad on me, but I believe you should read some books and blogs about javascript/jquery programming. Using foreign code, which you don't fully understand can lead to serious problems;).

Comment: i'm tried but it's not working, i've been wrong something... :(

Comment: i can't post the answer, this is the sample page:
www.eliven.net/ta/_shop/basket.asp

Comment: my bad, it should be $("#empty").hide(); in the add function

Comment: it's not working, maybe i've put this modify into the wrong place..and i'm not able to set the tag css

Comment: okay, one more try: replace `.length == 0` with `.length == 1` and push the `$("#empty").hide();` out of the if-block either into the success-block, or before the ajax-call, whatever suits you more.

Comment: now it's working :) thanks
but..i would like add another little modify..it's possible insert a button like "checkout" to link to another page?